# Turning a negative decimal into its binary representation

Tags: c, binary, decimal, data-conversion

I am trying to figure out a way I can take an input from the user, and display it in the BinRep[] array. Currently this program only works for positive numbers, however I am having a hard time finding a way to make it also work for negative numbers. Any ideas?

```
int n = atoi(argv[1]);
  int binRep[N];
  int i;
  int flippedNum;

  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    binRep[i] = 0;
  }

  i = 0;

  while (n > 0) {
    binRep[i] = n % 2;
    n = n / 2;
    i++;
  }

  for (i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    printf("%d", binRep[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you understand how signed numbers are represented in binary - ie two's complement? One way would be to convert the positive number to binary and then apply two's complement to get the negative representation. It seems you or whoever wrote the code may already be thinking along those lines as alluded to by the unused `flippedNum` variable.

Comment: Are you just trying to display the same number in binary as if the input were positive, but with a `-` in front of it?

Comment: no. the binary output should be the positive version of the number. I.E -7 and 7 should output the same (7 in binary).

Comment: Oh, then it sounds like you just need to add `n = abs(n);`. Don't forget to `#include <math.h>`

Comment: That's what I was originally going to do, but it just seemed way too simple. the output is correct, but I have a suspicious feeling it wont pass GitHub autograder for some reason... Anyways, thanks for the help! I guess Ill write back if its not allowed.

Comment: This is from the autograder:
```
  Random number:  -19198
  Expected binary representation:  11111111111111111011010100000010
  Actual binary representation  :  00000000000000000100101011111110
```

I guess it wants 2s Compliment?

Comment: Yup, that would be 2's complement

Comment: Can I still use n = abs(n); , or should I scrape that all together and try another approach?

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned int n = (unsigned int ) atoi( argv[1] );
unsigned int binRep[N];
```

should work

but the negativ number would be in the twos complement representation.

Comment: The input from the command line has to be a valid signed int. Thats why im having trouble with it otherwise.

Comment: 1.) the input from the command line is always a `char *`
2.) `atoi( argv[1] )` puts out an `int`
 3.) `(unsigned int)` converts this output to an `unsigned int`

Comment: could you explain to me why this works? I want to be able to fully understand and grasp it.

Comment: [twos complement wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)  and if you have troubles to understand my comment i would recommend "The C Programming Language"

Comment: I read the Wiki article and a few other stack overflow posts. I still don't fully grasp it, and this seems rather important. Is there anyway you can just give me a quick rundown of why this works?